# Cannot find module that is in package.json

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I currently have a file that only imports React, and Conversation from [react-conversation-form](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/react-conversation-form):

```
import React from 'react';
import Conversation from 'react-conversation-form';
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-conversation-form": "^2.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

Despite this, I am getting a `Cannot find module "react-conversation-form"` error. Is there a way to debug this?

Comment: Where is your file located relative to the package.json? It might be related to your folder structure. Would be nice if you could give some more information.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to execute `yarn install` ?

Comment: @3Dos I've run `yarn install` and if I do so again, it says already up to date.

Comment: @MartinReiche This is a react app using webpack. The package.json file is in the root. This specific file is located in app/javascript/components and is being rendered by a 'pack' in the app/javascript/packs folder.

Comment: Then like @MartinReiche said, it is probably a folder structure problem.

Comment: @3Dos I don't think so, I can use other modules from package.json in the same file as this one without a problem.

Comment: Hmmm. I think this is a problem inherent to the `react-conversation-form` package. See [https://npm.runkit.com/react-conversation-form](https://npm.runkit.com/react-conversation-form) . Looks like this package isn't working

Comment: @3Dos Oh ok thanks. I guess I will have to make my own version then ;)

Comment: You're welcome :) Sorry I couldn't help you more than that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following : `yarn cache clean`

and then perform : `yarn install`

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine. Is it possible that you've missed to execute "npm install" or it failed at some reason?

Comment: I've run `yarn install` but that doesn't fix anything. It says already up to date.